# noUiSlider - put date text in slider handle

Tags: slider, nouislider

I have the two-handle noUiSlider date range slider working, based on the example page of its website.

I am hoping to get the date text to appear in the handles, instead of the separate spans per the source code of the example page.

Comment: Replace `$("#event-start")` in the date example by `'-inline-<div class="tooltip"></div>'` from the tooltip example.

Comment: Embarrassed...I looked for but didnt find that example...Thank you.  (It takes a community to raise a programmer.)  Curious though, the <div class="tooltip"></div>  part didnt work.  I did get the css for tooltip, but still nothing.  Perhaps that part isnt necessary, but would you have further suggestions?